# Como retirar máscara de uma MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou usando **Visual Studio** para fazer uma aplicação usando `Windows Forms` em `C#` e preciso pegar todos os `Maskedtextbox` do formulário, sem as máscaras.

Estou usando o código abaixo neste momento. As `Maskedtexbox` são obtidas, mas não elimina as máscaras para fazer a comparação no `if`. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

```
foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
            {
                 //Analisa os Maskedtextbox
                if (c is MaskedTextBox)
                {
                    ((MaskedTextBox)c).Text.Replace("/", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("-", "");

                    if ((((MaskedTextBox)c).Tag == "*") && (((MaskedTextBox)c).Text.Length<=4))
                    {
                        retorno = true;
                        ((MaskedTextBox)c).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 192);
                        MessageBox.Show(c.Text);

                    }
                    else
                        ((MaskedTextBox)c).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode obter o valor da `MaskedTextBox` de duas formas, dependendo do que necessita:

**Permanente**

Na sua MaskedTextBox altere o valor da propriedade `TextMaskFormat` para `ExcludePromptAndLiterals`. Desta forma, pode utilizar `TextMaskFormat.Text` (em qualquer lugar) e o valor retornado será o texto sem a máscara.

**Temporário**

Se precisar do valor com a máscara noutras partes do código e deseja retirar a mascára somente para o `if` pode fazer o seguinte:

```
maskedTextBox.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
var valorSemMascara = maskedTextBox.Text;
maskedTextBox.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludePromptAndLiterals;
```

Nota:
Nenhuma das soluções altera o aspecto visual da `MaskedTextBox`.

Exemplo:

Um exemplo do código que pode utilizar dentro do evento de um botão (testado no VS2013, .NET4.5):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (MaskedTextBox mtBox in Controls.OfType<MaskedTextBox>())
    {
        mtBox.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
        MessageBox.Show(mtBox.Text); // Troque esta parte pelas suas condições.
        mtBox.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludePromptAndLiterals;
    }
}
```

Comment: de um exemplo por favor que seu código não funcionou.....